# how to use json property with #?

Tags: javascript, json, webstorm

Suppose I have a JSON property starting with `#`, for example:

```
var person = { "#name": "superman" };
```

How do I refer to it in my JS code? `person.#name` is not working in my editor (webstorm)?

It is supposed to be valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)?

```
var name = person["#name"];
```

There is more information on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets).